# assigning keys to objects created from arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have created a custom object from the following array

```
"result": [
               {
            "query": "NE30 1DP",
            "result": {
                "postcode": "NE30 1DP",
                "quality": 1,
                "eastings": 435958,
                "northings": 568671,
                "country": "England",
                "nhs_ha": "North East",
                "longitude": -1.439269,
                "latitude": 55.011303,
                "european_electoral_region": "North East",
                "primary_care_trust": "North Tyneside",
                "region": "North East",
                "lsoa": "North Tyneside 016C",
                "msoa": "North Tyneside 016",
                "incode": "1DP",
                "outcode": "NE30",
                "parliamentary_constituency": "Tynemouth",
                "admin_district": "North Tyneside",
                "parish": "North Tyneside, unparished area",
                "admin_county": null,
                "admin_ward": "Tynemouth",
                "ced": null,
                "ccg": "NHS North Tyneside",
                "nuts": "Tyneside",
                "codes": {
                    "admin_district": "E08000022",
                    "admin_county": "E99999999",
                    "admin_ward": "E05001130",
                    "parish": "E43000176",
                    "parliamentary_constituency": "E14001006",
                    "ccg": "E38000127",
                    "ccg_id": "99C",
                    "ced": "E99999999",
                    "nuts": "UKC22"
        }
    ]
```

The function I created is below

```
export const returnLatLonObj = (arr) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    arr.map(({ result: { latitude, longitude } }) => [latitude, longitude])
  );
};
```

This returns the following object

```
{
    "55.011303": -1.439269
}
```

However, what I would like is an object which looks something like the following:

```
{
  "latitude": 55.011303,
  "longitude": -1.439269
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `Object.fromEntries`. It's enough to generate a new object using `Array.prototype.map` only.

```js
const arr = [{
  "query": "NE30 1DP",
  "result": {
    "postcode": "NE30 1DP",
    "quality": 1,
    "eastings": 435958,
    "northings": 568671,
    "country": "England",
    "nhs_ha": "North East",
    "longitude": -1.439269,
    "latitude": 55.011303,
    "european_electoral_region": "North East",
    "primary_care_trust": "North Tyneside",
    "region": "North East",
    "lsoa": "North Tyneside 016C",
    "msoa": "North Tyneside 016",
    "incode": "1DP",
    "outcode": "NE30",
    "parliamentary_constituency": "Tynemouth",
    "admin_district": "North Tyneside",
    "parish": "North Tyneside, unparished area",
    "admin_county": null,
    "admin_ward": "Tynemouth",
    "ced": null,
    "ccg": "NHS North Tyneside",
    "nuts": "Tyneside",
    "codes": {
      "admin_district": "E08000022",
      "admin_county": "E99999999",
      "admin_ward": "E05001130",
      "parish": "E43000176",
      "parliamentary_constituency": "E14001006",
      "ccg": "E38000127",
      "ccg_id": "99C",
      "ced": "E99999999",
      "nuts": "UKC22"
    }
  }
}];

const returnLatLonObj = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(({ result: { latitude, longitude } }) => ({
    latitude,
    longitude
  }));
};

console.log(returnLatLonObj(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `map` with the correct assignment syntax already does the job ...

```js
const sampleDataList = [{
  "query": "NE30 1DP",
  "result": {
    "postcode": "NE30 1DP",
    "quality": 1,
    "eastings": 435958,
    "northings": 568671,
    "country": "England",
    "nhs_ha": "North East",
    "longitude": -1.439269,
    "latitude": 55.011303
  },
}];

// was ...
//
// /*export */const returnLatLonObj = (arr) => {
//  return Object.fromEntries(
//    arr.map(({ result: { latitude, longitude } }) => [latitude, longitude])
//  );
// };

// { "55.011303": -1.439269 }
// versus
// { "latitude": 55.011303, "longitude" :-1.439269 }

// should be ...
//
/*export */const returnLatLonObj = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(({ result: { latitude, longitude } }) =>
    ({ latitude, longitude })
  );
};

console.log(returnLatLonObj(sampleDataList));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```